# PHP simplexmlelement y html entities

Tags: php, simplexml

buenos días

Tengo que sacar un PDF que está en una base datos pero el valor me lo devuelve con caracteres especiales y cuando empleo Simplexmlelement me devuelve el error: "String cannot be parsed as XML"

Los caracteres especiales son los siguientes, entro otros:

```
&lt; &quot;
```

He probado intentando convertirlo antes de usar Simplexmlelement de esta forma:

```
$resp = htmlspecialchars_decode($resp);
```

Pero me sigue dando fallo

Gracias

Comment: Subiste el archivo a la base de datos, o en la base de datos tienes la ruta hacia el archivo almacenado en el servidor? El problema puede estar en la forma como estas almacenando la información en la variable $resp. Ya que esos caracteres que estas mostrando si se almacena como un string, htmlspecialchars_decode perfectamente podría decodificarlos.

Comment: Solo como prueba intenta codificar la variable con utf8_encode antes de pasarla por htmlspecialchars_decode.

Comment: no funciona utf8_encode. Por otro lado está guardado en un campo de una base de datos directamente,

Comment: Que tipo de dato es la información que contiene la variable  $resp?

Comment: Es el código de un archivo pdf